# Al insertar datos en una tabla, los datos estan en [object, object]

Tags: javascript, html, css, nodejs, visual-studio

Los datos estan alamacenados de la siguiente forma:

```
datos = {
"id" 1,
"patologias": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "nombre": "Patología cardíaca"
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "nombre": "Patología Dérmica"
            }
        ]
}
```

E introduzco en la tabla los datos y solo el nombre de las patologias, en la columna de patologias de esta forma:

```
for (var i = 0; i < datos.length; i++){
  id.innerHTML = datos[i].id;
  patologias.innerHTML = datos[i]["patologias"][i]["nombre"];
}
```

Pero en la tabla me sale:

```
[object Object]
```

Al poner JSON.stringify(datos[i]["patologias"][i]["nombre"]) me devuelve solo la primera patologia (patología cardíaca) la segunda no.
patologias.innerHTML es la fila de la tabla donde quiero que esten los datos.

¿Tengo que hacer un for de patologias y crear una fila por patología?

Comment: No cuadra tu supuesto objeto `datos` con lo que pones despues. Debes crear un [example] para que podamos ayudarte. Ahora mismo tu pregunta no tiene demasiado sentido y tendriamos que hacer demasiado esfuerzo para ayudarte, y no somos tan buenos :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya lo solucioné, recorriendo los objetos de patologías directamente y luego guardando lo que me interesaba.

```
for (var j = 0; j< pacientes[i]["patologias"].length; j++){ // Recorro las patologías
    pat = document.createElement("p"); // Creo un p por cada patologia
    pat.innerHTML = pacientes[i]["patologias"][j]["nombre"]; // Asigno el valor
    patologias.appendChild(pat); // Asocio el p a la columna
}
```

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Aunque no queda muy claro en tu pregunta que es lo que pretendes hacer, si lo que quieres es asignar el contenido de tu objeto a un div, tendrás que hacer algo como lo siguiente:

```js
datos = {
"id": 1,
"patologias": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "nombre": "Patología cardíaca"
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "nombre": "Patología Dérmica"
            }
        ]
}

let contenido = '';
for (var patologia in datos.patologias) {
  contenido += '<p>Id: ' + datos.patologias[patologia].id + '</p>';
  contenido += '<p>Nombre: ' + datos.patologias[patologia].nombre + '</p>';
}

$('.patologias').html(contenido);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="patologias"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`[object][object]` es la representación de un objeto en `string`, javaScript lo hace cuando no encuentra la propiedad de un objeto, o cuando de alguna manera intentas renderizar en el [html](/questions/tagged/html) un objeto, si te sale `[object][object]` es porque estas accediendo al objeto en si y no a una propiedad en ves de acceder a

ej:

```js
const user = {
  nombre: 'Juan'
}
console.log(user.nombre);
```